# Creating a generic RestTemplate service, without specifying the Model

Tags: json, resttemplate

I'm trying to call a service using RestTemplate where I call service using below code:

```
Object obj;//Taken from @RequestBody
ResponseEntity<?> response = (ResponseEntity<?>)
restTemplate.postForEntity(url,obj,Object.class);
```

Here as can be seen, I've used Object.class instead of the actual model class which the service returns.

This piece of code works with content-type and Accept as application/json respectively.
However if content-type is application/json and Accept is application/xml it doesn't work. Give exception as:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract 
response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class
 java.lang.Object] and content type [application/xml;charset=UTF-8]
```

I have tried other methods like: exchange(...) by passing a ParameterisedTypeRefference. However that didn't solve the purpose. Gave the same exception. As ParameterisedTypeRefference also expects the Model class type to be defined in it which comes as response.

Comment: Did you try implementing your own `HttpMessageConverter`?

Comment: @Nati I havn't tried it yet. Can you please suggest me a link which would help me in doing the same